# conversion from const pointer to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

i'm trying to pass rectangle constructor ref to const Point* so i can add the actual Point* to addPoint function (will past her code).

well how i know it is that when i use for example "int& num = other" i get ref to "other" so i can change other... so when i use "const int& num = other" i can only see whats inside other without the ability to change its content.

so i figured that when i use "const Point*& p = other" i atually have the content of other (which is an address of Point) but in a way i cant change it.

so if all above is true, why cant i send it to addPoint which receive Point* ? as i understand the compiler will copy the address from "p1" which is an address of Point and will paste it in fresh Point* in new slot in the vector.... isn't that whats happanes ?

any way i get:

```
invalid conversion from ‘const Point*’ to ‘Point*’ [-fpermissive]
```

here is my code (Rectangle is inherent from Polygon)

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(const int& color, const Point*& p1, const Point*& p2, const Point*& p3, const Point*& p4) : Polygon(color, "Rectangle")
{
    addPoint(p1);
    addPoint(p2);
    addPoint(p3);
    addPoint(p4);
}
```

and Polygon with addPoint function:

```
#include "Point.h"
#include "Polygon.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;


Polygon::Polygon() : _points(), _color(0), _type("")
{}

Polygon::~Polygon() {
    clear();
}

Polygon::Polygon(const Polygon& other) : _points(), _color(other._color), _type(other._type)
{
    getDataFrom(other);
}


Polygon::Polygon(const int& color, const string& type) : _points(), _color(color) , _type(type)
{
}


void Polygon::addPoint(Point* p) {
    Point* newp = new Point; //create a copy of the original pt
    newp->setX(p->getX());
    newp->setY(p->getY());
    _points.push_back(newp);
}

void Polygon::clear()
{
    vector<Point*>::iterator iter = _points.begin();
    cout << "DELETING POLYGON: BEGIN" << endl;
    while (iter != _points.end()) {
        delete (*iter);
        iter++;
    }
    cout << "DELETING POLYGON: END" << endl;
}


}
```

thanks !

Comment: Why are you passing the pointers by reference?  Pointers don't take up a lot of room so you should pass them by value, since you are not modifying them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `addPoint()` takes a non-const pointer:

```
void Polygon::addPoint(Point* p) {
```

But you're trying to pass it a `const Point*`, hence the error. The compiler doesn't know that you end up not modifying what `p` points to - so it could be a violation of `const` to let you do what you're trying to do.

For instance, if `addPoint()` did:

```
void Polygon::addPoint(Point* p) { p->setX(42); }
```

It would be clearly wrong to let you pass a `const Point*` in.

However, since you don't actually *need* `p` to point to a non-const `Point` you can just change the signature to reflex this:

```
void Polygon::addPoint(const Point* p) {
```

Comment: thanks
but what if i do want to be able to change the address inside the vector later ?
why cant i take one const variable and copy it to a non const ? 

its seems right to me to have one variable that i don't want to change (the one i got from the constructor caller) and paste --its value-- into some other place which i will be able to modify (like the one in the cevtor)...

Comment: @doron-BGUbgu You can take a const *variable* and copy it to a non const variable, but you can't copy a pointer-to-const or reference-to-const to just a pointer or reference because that would potentially violate `const`. The issue isn't changing the *value* - the value here is just the address, you can just the address of a `const T*` - the issue is changing the pointee.

Comment: Hence the difference between `const Point*` and `Point *const`.

Answer (score 0):

`const Point*` means "pointer to `const Point`", in other words the object pointed to by the pointer is constant. You cannot assign it to a variable of type `Point*` (which means "pointer to non-const `Point`"), because it would allow you to modify the underlying `Point` object.

If you want a *constant pointer* to *non-constant* `Point`, declare it as `Point* const`.

Comment: **thanks**.  so how could i state that i want const pointer to Point ?

Comment: @doron-BGUbgu `Point* const p;`